# PIC M-Stack "add . to include" confusion

Tags: pic, usb, mplab, xc8

I am experimenting with the open source USB stack called [M-Stack](http://www.signal11.us/oss/m-stack/) for the first time.  I decided to start by building the HID mouse sample application, but I had to create my own project configuration because the PIC MCU I am using is not supported with the default project configurations supplied.

Because I was creating my own project configuration I followed the M-Stack page instructions for "Making Your Own Project", which can be found about 2/3 of the way down the page I linked to above.

I added the usb/include directory to my project path as instructed; that makes perfect sense.  But the IDE still gives some complaints about unresolved identifiers after this.  The resolution was to follow step 4, which states

> Add . to the include path of your project.

I did this and the last of my IDE errors disappeared.  That's great, except I don't understand why! I don't know what "add . to the include path" means.

Is anybody able to enlighten me as to what this means?

Comment: "." refers to the current working directory in a lot of file systems. It probably needs that to see your own include files, which are presumably in the current working directory.

Comment: I think that might be it.  I just found out that the current working directory is where the Makefile is stored, and the unresolved header files it complained about are one directory level up.

So when I added ../. to the include path, the IDE knew where to find the files.

Thanks very much.